# Как сделать так, чтобы телеграмм-бот не спамил после перезапуска

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я новичок. У меня есть бот для телеги, написан он на telebot, python. Проблема состоит в том, что если бот вырубается, а пользователь продолжает отправлять ему сообщения, то при повторном запуске бота он начинает спамить, отвечая на заданные во время неактивности команды. Это можно как-то исправить? Ну, чтобы как только я снова запускаю бота, он "забывал" все те сообщения? Спасибо заранее)

Comment: Возможно, это настраивается. Но если нет, можно попробовать сделать костыль. Например, посмотреть у сообщений время и сравнить с текущим. Нужно только убедиться, что там и там будет UTC, т.е. время без учета часового пояса

Comment: Да, есть такой способ всего в одну команду) Можно прописать `skip_pending=True`, когда формируете экземпляр бота. `bot = telebot.TeleBot('token', skip_pending=True)`

Answer (score 2):

Пропишите: `skip_pending=True` в `bot = telebot.TeleBot`.

Пример:

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token', skip_pending=True)
```

Тогда бот будет отвечать только на последний запрос, а не спамить отвечая на все запросы.